# Confusion about IGBT safe operating area

Tags: power-electronics, igbt

I have a pair of [IXXH110N65C4](https://www.littelfuse.com/%7E/media/electronics/datasheets/discrete_igbts/littelfuse_discrete_igbts_xpt_ixxh110n65c4_datasheet.pdf.pdf) IGBTs in a stacked configuration:

[image: Coil driver circuit]

It appears from the datasheet that the transistors can switch a current of 600A on and off, with a pulse length of up to 1ms (at 25c and assuming no transients).

Is that true?

To put another way, can I turn on one of these IGBTs with a couple of hundred volts across it, allow the current to build up to 500A over a few hundred uS, and then turn it off without it exploding?

I know it's probably obvious if you understand what all the terms in the datasheet mean. But.. having misunderstood the terms and blown up quite a few expensive transistors, I would like to double check.

Comment: maybe it's me, but in that data sheet I don't see a forward bias SOA graph. A reverse one, yes. But not a forward one.

Comment: @Neil_UK Yeah, I noticed that. I figure that must mean it's a square?

Comment: A 600A for up to 1ms at 25°C is what it is, but at a higher temperature that peak current drops, so that's what you should watch out for. It would be better to reduce the peak current to 300A OR get an IGBT which has at least 50% higher peak current rating than the highest you expect in your circuit, just to be on the safe side.

Comment: @Drew I figure that means they're not telling you, why!

Comment: "turn it off without it exploding" -- note that no layout is provided at present, so we can't comment on loop inductance; and, if 1uF is all the supply bypass that's present, note that 600A into 1uF gives a rate of 600V/us, which is to say, if the stored current doesn't find another sink path within about half a microsecond, the transistors are toast! In general, we can model the supply as an RLC network, and solve for this response.

Comment: @TimWilliams thanks, I'm aware of that, that's it's own problem. What I'm concerned with here is whether I'm reading the datasheet correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Theoretically, the answer is "yes."  What the ICM value means is that you are still in the operating area (not to be confused with safe operating area) of the device.

You can see from the graph below, which is taken from your data sheet link, that at VGE of 15 volts, IC can be almost 500 amps.  You would have to go a little higher on VGE to get to 600 amps, and you can't go too much higher without exceeding the 20-volt maximum for VGE.  So what ICM really means is the maximum current at the maximum VGE.  It's the "ceiling" above which the device simply cannot operate as an IGBT.

If you tried to operate here, you would have to watch out for a number of issues.  First, the part would need to cool back down after every pulse, because 500 amps at 10 volts VCE is 5,000 watts, not including the switching losses which will be substantial.  So your duty cycle will have to be low.  At these currents and switching times, even small stray inductance will cause you to exceed your 650-volt maximum, which will have the part breaking down.  Remember, all that current and di/dt has to go through those skinny leads, and internally they are bonded to the die somehow.  And this part is not going to be easy to switch; you will need fast switching times and the dv/dt will drive the gate through the reverse capacitance (not to mention driving the gate capacitance itself; 5500 pF).  You will have to drive the gate to nearly 20 volts, and keep any oscillations on the gate drive low to stay below the maximum value for VGE.  You'll probably want to drive the gate negative to get good "off" times.

However, the part manufacturer presumably is doing this somehow, so it must be possible!

[image]

Comment: Due to loop inductance, a slow turn-off can indeed be advantageous; drivers with desat protection often provide a "fault" output channel intended to turn off the gate slower. To make use of this, one must design to include the falling edge (and corresponding extreme power level) in the SOA.

Answer (score 1):

I asked littlefuse if the Pc limit of 880W is time averaged, or instantaneous. Because if it *is* instantainious, then that would certainly be exceeded by this usage. Here is the answer I received:

> Pc of 880W:
>
> - This is by calculation.
> - Package thermal of 0.17°C/W was measured value during development
> - Per design this IGBT has junction temperature, TJ max of 175°C
> - From 0.17°C/W and TJ max of 175°C, allowable power dissipation while case temperature, Tc =25°C, is 880W.
>
> Transient heat dissipation:
>
> During turn off, you may calculate turn-off loss by Joule. Simulation
> may return result by Watt by dividing Joule value by turn-off time,
> but unless this keeps happening without interval, Joule value over
> entire cycle (time between one ON and next ON event) to calculate
> dissipation is more appropriate.
>
> You need to keep IGBT TJ up to 175°C during transient, then keep
> “average” dissipation under the Pc value calculated from possible case
> temperature – this depends on how it is cooled - and package thermal.